# Twitter is not being loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension, where I need to load certain websites in the iframe, I added this code

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(info) {
      let headers = info.responseHeaders;
      for (let i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
          let header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
          if (header == 'x-frame-options' || header == 'frame-options') {
              headers.splice(i, 1); // Remove header
          }
      }
      return {
          responseHeaders: headers
      };
  }, {
      urls: ["<all_urls>"], // Pattern to match all http(s) pages
      types: ['sub_frame']
  },
  ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

Which sipmply remove the `x-frame-options` or `frame-options` from the header and let most of the websites be loaded in the iframe, but this function does run when the site is Twitter, but if I remove the `['sub_frame']` option, Twitter also starts working, but that is not what I want, because if I keep that removed, this function will run on every Http(s) request.

What is the problem here?

How can I make it work?

And if I keep that `['sub_frame']` option removed, will this make any effect on performance?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently twitter uses iframes on its own site. Simply skip processing based on the URL of the parent page that performs the request.

- Available as [initiator](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-details-initiator) in Chrome 63+.
- Available as [originUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived#details) in Firefox 48+.

---

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  info => {
    if ((info.initiator || info.originUrl) === 'https://twitter.com') {
      return;
    }
    // process the request
    // .....................
    // .....................
  }, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>'],
    types: ['sub_frame'],
  },
  ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

Comment: the function doesn't even execute when the site is Twitter.com

Comment: Just tried and I see this function **runs** on twitter pages and intercepts iframes for a card: https://puu.sh/E4mym/4e89cea146.png

Comment: why can't I see any such thing, in my case nothing loads up

Comment: I change `types: ["sub_frame"]` to `types: ["sub_frame", 'xmlhttprequest']`, it works, but it is not what I want

Comment: I don't know what happens in your browser. I don't see how adding xmlhttprequest would change anything, it doesn't make sense to me, so I can't help apparently.

Comment: Maybe you have another extension that uses webRequest so [it wins](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#conflict_resolution).

Comment: in your case the type was`sub_frame`, but in my case, it was `xmlhttprequest` [screenshot](https://imgur.com/5dIgRGG)

Comment: Your screenshot shows a xmlhttprequest, not an iframe, so how is it related to the problem? To me it looks totally unrelated.

Comment: Anyway, I can't make any sense out of this so I'm out.